# How to refresh a client side component inside a server component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a server side component and two client components inside it.

```
/page.tsx

  <NewItemModal /> //client component 
  <DataTable /> //client component
```

I make a new item with `NewItemModal` component:

```
  const onSubmit = async (formData: FormValues) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5162/api/Item', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        
        router.push('/item');
        reset(); 
      } else {
        console.error('Error in sending the request');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error communicating with the server', error);
    }
  };
```

`DataTable` component is a table of items.
Now I want to refresh `DataTable` .
I used `router.push('/item');` or `router.refresh();` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried location.reload() ?

Comment: I think it doesn't best practice.

Comment: Yeah! you are right @S.M_Emamian.

Comment: What are  you using? import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'; OR  import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

Comment: According to the official website router.refresh() working in app root not in pages. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router

Comment: @NaveenNizam I'm using `next/navigation`

Comment: In the app folder or pages?